# How to take ms access file's datas from web application to ms sql server without saving ms access file

Tags: c#, sql, file, ms-access, httpcontext

I create a web application. users upload ms access file then I save some data from it to ms sql server.

I use web handler to save mdb file to server like;

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
            if (context.Request.Files.Count == 1)
            {
                HttpFileCollection files = context.Request.Files;
                for (int i = 0; i < files.Count; i++)
                {
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
                    HttpPostedFile file = files[i];
                    string filename = context.Server.MapPath("~/Uploads/" + System.IO.Path.GetFileName(file.FileName));
                    file.SaveAs(filename);
                 }
            }
    }
```

Then I coded to take some datas from mdb file accessing from upload folder.
I wonder that is there any solution to take mdb file's datas without saving to server.

Answer (score 0):

That's easily answered: no, there isn't.

If you want to work with Access databases, they have to be saved to a file. There's no real alternative to it.

If you really want it to be saved in memory, an easy solution would be a [ram drive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAM_drive)